# invalid regex javascript

Tags: javascript

Can you explain me why this regex is invalid ?

```
new RegExp("^(0|\+33)+[0-9]{9}$");
```

Validate by regex online

Comment: escape `+` character

Comment: No, work with this site

Comment: with regex online you don't have to worry about the string escapes in addition to regex escapes. That's why it works with regex online but not in this example, because you're constructing the RegExp with a string. As @MarkMeyer said, if you use a regex literal you won't run into the string escape problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex work as expected with regex literals.
 With the string literals you need to double escape the special chars.

```js
const r = /^(0|\+33)+[0-9]{9}$/;
console.log(r.test('0782896736'));
console.log(r.test('+33782896736'));
console.log(r.test('blabla'));


const regexp = new RegExp('^(0|\\+33)+[0-9]{9}$');
console.log(regexp.test('0782896736'));
console.log(regexp.test('+33782896736'));
console.log(regexp.test('blabla'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a double backslash before the first `+`, like this:

```
new RegExp("^(0|\\+33)+[0-9]{9}$");
```

When JavaScript evaluates the string, it reads `\+` as simply `+`. Then the RegExp sees `|+`, which is two Regex operators back to back (`or` and `repeat 1 to infinite times`)...which is invalid.

Comment: You forgot the double backslash.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thanks, I got in too much of a hurry. Fixed now

Comment: `Invalid regular expression: /^(0|+33)+[0-9]{9}$/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: @Matthis.h not sure what browser you're using, but I just copied and pasted my code into `Chrome/75.0.3770.90` console, and it worked perfectly. Returned this: `/^(0|\+33)+[0-9]{9}$/`

Comment: I'm using `Chrome 75.0.3770.100`